# How to remove bottom margin

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am practicing bootstrap for the first time and having quite a problem.
Here I have added two horizontal lines at the top and bottom of my navbar. I am having an unexpected margin at the bottom between the navbar and that horizontal line in golden color.  `<div style="height:10px; background: rgb(228, 240, 1)"></div>` this one. Please help.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Nav-Bar -->
    <div style="height:10px; background: rgb(228, 240, 1)"></div>
        <nav class= "navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Umair Tahir</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcollapseCMS">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcollapseCMS">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="MyProfile.php" class="nav-link"> <i class="fas fa-user text-success"></i> My Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="Dashboard.php" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="Posts.php" class="nav-link">Posts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="Categories.php" class="nav-link">Categories</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="Admins.php" class="nav-link">Manage Admins</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="Comments.php" class="nav-link">Comments</a>
                        </li><li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="Blog.php?page=1" class="nav-link">Live Blog</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="Logout.php" class="nav-link text-danger"> <i class="fas fa-user-times"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>  
                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div style="height:10px; background: rgb(228, 240, 1)"></div>  
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add it to your **CSS** or to **<style>...</style>** tag - `.navbar { margin-bottom: 0!important; }`

Answer (score 0):

The navbar class inside bootstrap.css contains the command margin-bottom: 20px by default.

To remove the margin here, you can add the following command to the line with the nav tag;

```
style = "margin-bottom: 0px;"
```

Final Version;

```
<nav class= "navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
```